# Use CSS framework through npm in Electron application

Tags: html, css, node.js, npm, electron

I have installed `bulma` through `npm` in my electron project as a dependency. However, I am forced to do something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css" />
```

What is the *best practice* here? I've read I have to use `npm-css`, but I am not sure how the `import` statement would yield the css in my `html` file. In other words, what are some other alternatives to including css installed through `npm`?